# Spring boot application.properties maven multi-module projects

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

We are using spring boot in a multi-module project.

We have a Domain access module which has the common domain object classes, repositories, together with configuration for the datasource, JPA, Hibernate, etc. These are configured using a application.properties. We put all this configuration into the common module to save duplicating these common configurations in the higher level modules.

This all works fine when building the domain module, so the configurations are loaded correctly in the test units.

However the problems start when we try to use the domain module in the higher layer modules; they have their own application.properties which means Spring loads them and not the the Domain module application.properties, which this means the data source is not configured because only the higher module application.properties are loaded.

What we would like is both the domain module and higher level application properties to be loaded by Spring. But we can't see any easy way to do this.

I'm thinking this must be a common problem, and wonder if there any recommended solutions for this problem?

As we are using spring-boot the solution should ideally use annotations instead of applictionContext.xml.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe you should only use `application.properties` in the top-level aggregator project?

You can always use `@PropertySource` in the child projects to configure them with a name that is specific to their use case.

Or you can use different names for each project and glue them together in the top-level project using `spring.config.location` (comma-separated).

Comment: If we do have the properties file at top-level aggregator project how can we write tests for the child projects ? Should we have those properties again in child projects' test resources ?

Comment: What i did was created another submodule, with all the test properties and which is imported in all other modules with scope test. That way no need to duplicate properties to all sub modules.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @Dave Syer. The idea of splitting an application into multiple modules is that each of those is an independent unit, in this case a jar file. Theoretically you could split each of those jar files into their own source repositories, and then use them across multiple projects. Let's say you want to reuse these domain classes in both a web and batch application, if all the APPLICATION level configuration is stored within each of the individual modules, it severely reduces their reusability.

IMO only the aggregating module should contain all of the configuration necessary to run as an application, everything else is simply a dependency that can be remixed and reused as necessary.

Comment: I'm looking for is a good convention for setting the default property values in the child modules. Then the aggregator module need only concern them selves with changing the child module properties they need to change, not all of the child module properties. If you think about it this is how Spring Boot works; it has commonly used defaults for its JDBC, JPA, WEB projects and then you need only change the ones you are interested in.

Comment: So in that case why not use a spring boot AutoConfiguration? If you're really setting properties (datasource urls, etc.) i don't think that's necessarily the same as what spring boot is doing - they're picking the appropriate dependencies and environment-agnostic settings, setting something like a datasource is by definition app specific. 

To me at least, each jar should contain the code only, and the application-specific configuration should live in the aggregating app.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe another approach could be to define specific profiles for each module and use the application.properties file just to specify which profiles are active
using the [spring.profiles.include](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-adding-active-profiles)  property.

```
domain-module
- application.properties
- application-domain.properties

app-module
- application.properties
- application-app.properties
```

and into the application.properties file of app-module

```
spring.profiles.include=domain,app
```

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can do (besides only using application.properties at the top-level as Dave Syer mentions) is to name the properties file of the domain module something like `domainConfig.properties`.

That way you avoid the name clash with `application.properties`.

`domainConfig.properties` would contain all the data needed for the domain module to be able to tested on it's own. The integration with the rest of the code can easily be done either using multiple `@PropertySource` (one for `domainConfig.properties` and one for `application.properties`) or configuring a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in your Java Config (check out [this](https://dzone.com/articles/properties-spring) tutorial) that refers to all the needed property files

Comment: That's pretty much what I said, but if it makes it clearer to anyone, it's all good. I wouldn't advise using another `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` (it just duplicates the effort of the one that is already there), ut I guess it's an option if you can't change the `spring.config.*` properties at runtime.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your answer, I thought you meant ditch the properties file in the domain altogether and use the only the properties file at the top level. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

in spring-boot since `2.4` support `spring.config.import`

e.g

```
application.name=myapp
spring.config.import=developer.properties

# import from other module
spring.config.import=classpath:application-common.properties
```

or with `spring.config.activate.on-profile`

```
spring.config.activate.on-profile=prod
spring.config.import=prod.properties
```

ref: https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4