# Environment specific YML files in spring boot module jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Suppose spring boot project **X** uses another spring boot project **Y** as a module.

**X.war** spring boot project loads YML files using profiles concept.

**Y.jar** is a dependency added to **X.war**

But **Y.jar** file also can load the YML files using profiles concept?

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138494/spring-boot-application-properties-maven-multi-module-projects

Comment: The Y.jar's properties YML file should be env specific.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot is a runtime framework. It can load only one `application.yml` at runtime in the `classpath`.

Module X used another dependency Y and Module X and Y both has their own `application.yml`. means, applicatioin.yml of module X will load it at runtime.

```
X 
|--- Y
```

To resolve this, we have to make a copy of the application.yml as `yconfig.yml` and load it runtime in module Y.

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootConfiguration
@PropertySource(value = "yconfig.yml")
public class ModuleYConfig {
    
}
```

Comment: These yml files which Y loads are also environment specific.