# Spring Boot project not binding @Value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am in the process of migrating an existing multi-module maven project to spring boot 2.6.1 and I've populated application.properties in the resources folder of one of the modules (the one with the SpringBootApplication entry point and with the spring boot maven plugin).
I am able to access these properties from any module in the project via the application environment. However binding a property using @Value does not work

The following is my project structure

```
PROJ
└── pom.xml
└── ModuleA
    └── src
        └── main
            └── java
                └── com.example
                    └── abc
                        └── configuration
                            └── TestConfig.java
                        └── MyApplication.java
            └── resources
                └── application.properties
    └── pom.xml
└── ModuleB
```

Why does property binding fail with either @ConfigurationProperties or @Value? (I am tring to bind all datasource properties to a DataSourceProperties bean in ModuleB using @ConfigurationProperties as described in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources) - but this also does not work.)

Things I've tried:

- placing application.properties in a config directory;
- specifying the location of the resources in the pom file;
- creating a fresh multi-module project with the same structure (It does work in this
  "clean" project so the problem must be in the existing configuration
  of the migrated project. I have tried to compare the differences
  between the two projects but applying similar configuration I still
  cannot get the auto-binding to work in my migrated project.)

The code:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PROJ</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>PROJ</name>

    <modules>
        <module>ModuleA</module>
        <module>ModuleB</module>
        <!-- Other modules -->
    </modules>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <develop.mode>true</develop.mode>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <develop.mode>false</develop.mode>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <!-- Project Properties -->
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- In House Modules -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>ModuleB</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>ModuleA</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-plugin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-plugin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.0-BETA</version>
                <classifier>BETA</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security-oauth.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security-oauth.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Various other dependencies -->
            
        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Various plugins  -->
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

**ModuleA/pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>PROJ</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>ModuleA</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ModuleA</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- In House Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>ModuleB</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
# My datasource properties
app.datasource.myds.username=TestName
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WSMBootApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WSMBootApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

**TestConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Value("${app.datasource.myds.username}")
    public String un;

    @Bean(name = "testbean1")
    @Primary
    public Boolean testbean1() {
        System.out.println("Value un: " + un); // prints null
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    @Bean(name = "testbean2")
    public Boolean testbean2(Environment env) {
        System.out.println("Env property: " + env.getProperty("app.datasource.myds.username")); // prints TestName 
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use the properties of one module in another like this, but you can do something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23139586/1712172) suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause for why Spring Boot was not autowiring my properties with @Value or @ConfigurationProperties
It turns out that the project I am trying to migrate implemented a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean which was failing to initialize the properties properly. I have done away with that bean and the application is now loading and autowiring all properties from application.properties (from all modules)